# How to hide image null icon from form until user capture them?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

As you can see, when user open the form, he got an image null until he captures an image with the camera. How to hide default NULL icons?
[Report form with ionic camera native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKlSo.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<img [src]="imgSrc" id="imgPlacement" ngShow="imgSrc !== undefined">
```

Comment: It works, but I've been used it with *ngIf, because I'm not using angularJS. :)